# C++ function to preform division

Tags: c++

Im trying to make a function that does division with out the / symbol

```
long  q(int nm1, int nm2)
{
  long q = 0;

   while ( num1 > num2)
    {
    some subtraction here    
    }
return q;

}
```

the idea is to assume the input is in order and the first is to be divided by the second.
This means subtract the second from the first until the second is less then the first number.

I tried many different ways to do this but for what ever reason I cant hit it.

For now I am assuming the number is positive and wont return division by zero (I can fix that later by calling my other functions)

Comment: Well, how about you show us one of the "many different ways" you tried, maybe the one you think is closest? This is not really a programming problem, you just need to know how you would do it on a piece of paper and then translate it into code.

Comment: It is hard to divide without the operator. And with subtraction you will be able to do only if the number is perfectly divisible. But I will think about it nonetheless!!!!!!

Comment: Yea. I think you should transfer the question to the mathematics.

Comment: @IcyFlame Au contraire: It is very easy, and you can implement it even if its not perfectly divisible.

Comment: @IcyFlame You think mathexchange really wants to answer a 1st grade arithmetic question?

Comment: @us2012: please enlighten me.

Comment: Yes you can do it if you have a way to deal with division by zero and negatives which I do.

Comment: @IcyFlame You keep subtracting until the number is less than the divisor. Now you have the quotient, and the number is the remainder.

Comment: Does `exp(log(nm1) - log(nm2))` count?

Comment: And please tell us if u want the integer part only or both integer and fractional part?

Comment: @Barmar: again you give us the integer part only not the fractional part. Any idea how we can get the fractional part?

Comment: @IcyFlame Fraction is ignored, just like the built-in `/` operator.

Comment: @IcyFlame His function returns a `long`, not `float`, so he's obviously not interested in the fraction.

Comment: @IcyFlame Im not looking for perfection here if I wanted that ill just float the / symbol also have your heard of static insertion statements? they force what ever in the insert stream to be constrained to what ever you want.

Comment: no matter just got the loop to work after that i can add on. I have like 40 extra functions that deal with situations. This one for what ever reason was an issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This means subtract the the second from the first until the second is less than the first number.

And what's the problem with that?

```
int div(int num, int den)
{
    int frac;
    for (frac = 0; num >= den; num -= den, frac++)
        ;

    return frac;
}
```

Comment: You will get only the integer part of the answer here. Not the decimal part. How do you plan to deal with that?

Comment: You need to handle division by 0 and negative numbers, but the basic idea is sound.

Comment: @icyflame In no way. Integer division truncates. (Go grab some general sense of C before smartassing others...)

Comment: Well, in case you noticed a/3.0 gives a float as an answer. @us2012

Comment: @icyflame that's easy force static int in the input stream. im not concerned about decimals  atm.

Comment: any way h2co3's solution worked the num-= was'nt present when I tried it and caused it to blow up.

Comment: @Someguy I don't know what's going on, I haven't edited the answer. And I just tried it, and this works *for non-negative integers.* Extension to negatives and check for division by zero are left as an exercise to you.

Comment: @H2CO3 Negatives are dealt with already I just needed the for loop as i couldn't recall the syntax in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

What you're original post is trying to do is the **Division by repeated subtraction** algorithm. Have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm):

> The simplest division algorithm, historically incorporated into a
>   greatest common divisor algorithm presented in Euclid's Elements, Book
>   VII, Proposition 1, finds the remainder given two positive integers
>   using only subtractions and comparisons

```
while  N ≥ D do
  N := N - D
end
return N
```

Just add a counter in your while loop to keep track of the number of iterations (which is what you will want to return) and after your loop N will contain your remainder (if it is not 0 of course).

Answer (score 1):

This code will work only if the num and den are integer values.

```
int main( int num, int den )
    {
        if(den==0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            while(num!=0)
            {
                num = num - den;    
            }
        }
       return 0;         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just improving the above answer slightly. 
Use modulus

```
long div(int num, int den)
{
    int frac;
    int num2 = num;

    for (frac = 0; num2 >= den; num2 -= den, frac++)
        ;
// i needed the original num and den. 

  return ( (long) frac )+( num % den );

// casts frac to long then adds the modulus remainder of the values.
}
```

Comment: No. This is (a) wrong, and (b) if you had an assignment to implement division without `/`, then `%` wouldn't be allowed either.

Answer (score 0):

just a bit optimization: you don't want to have linear time complexity with the input value

```
int div(int num, int den)
{
    int result = 0;
    int i;
    long long x;
    long long y;
    if (num < 0) return -div(-num, den);
    if (den < 0) return -div(num, den);
    if (num < den) return 0;

    x = num;
    y = den;
    i = 0;
    while((i < 32) && (x > (y << (i+1)))) i++;
    for(;i>0; i++)
    {
       if (x > (y << i))
       {
           x -= y;
           result += 1 << i; 
       }
    } 

    return result;
}
```